Error coneccion Netbeans IDE 8.2 a microsoft sql server management studio
estoy creando una GUI para una base de datos, al crear la conexion me manda el mensaje:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: La propiedad "encrypt" está establecida en "true" y la propiedad "trustServerCertificate" está establecida en "false", pero el controlador no pudo establecer una conexión segura a SQL Server mediante el cifrado de Capa de sockets seguros (SSL): Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. ClientConnectionId:9e682309-3743-4083-9d7d-34cb4b69db1b
Aqui esta el codigo:
package BD;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ConexionBD {

    Connection conectar = null;
    String Usuario = "PracticaUser";
    String Contraseña = "admin";
    String bd = "Practica4";
    String ip = "localhost";
    String puerto = "1433";

    // Corrección en la cadena de conexión
    String cadena = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + ip + ":" + puerto + ";databaseName=" + bd;

    public Connection establecerConexion() {
        try {
            // Corrección en la cadena de conexión
            conectar = DriverManager.getConnection(cadena, Usuario, Contraseña);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexion a la base de datos: activa");
            System.out.println("Conexion a la base de datos: activa");

        } catch (HeadlessException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Conexion a la base de datos: negada" + e.toString());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexion a la base de datos: negada" + e.toString());
            System.out.println("Conexion a la base de datos: negada" + e.toString());
        }
        return conectar;
    }
}

